How to manage alert box with multiple dependencies?
I have two parallel & independent functions named function a() ->Bool & function b() ->Bool
Now If any of this function fails I want to show alert box
Note: I can not put one function into another. both func can take ~5 second to complete
Tried approach: created two flag inside a() & b() named var aCompleted: Bool var bCompleted
&
func showAlert() {
if aCompleted && bCompleted {
 // show UIAlertController....
}

I am looking for better approach, Please guide.

func a() async throws -> Bool {
 ....
}

func b() async throws -> Bool {
....
}

do {
 const boolA = try await a()
 const boolB = try await b()
  if (boolA && boolB) {
  //show alert
 }
} catch {
print("Failed with error \(error)")
}


Easiest approach would be to use Dispatch Groups.
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var aSuccess = false
    var bSuccess = false

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        aSuccess = self.a()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        bSuccess = self.b()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        if !aSuccess || !bSuccess {
            self.showAlert()
        }
    }

The .notify function is called only when both the functions have been executed.
